# COMException was unhandled by user code(Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE508) win8 metro apps

Tags: com, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, xmlreader

I'm writing a little application on WinRT Metro Apps. I need to read an xml file and i get a awful COMException :/

This is which should read this xml:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = await
   Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation
   .GetFolderAsync("Common");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile storageFile = await
   storageFolder.GetFileAsync("testFile.xml");

var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

XmlDocument doc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromAsync(storageFile);
```

Can somebody give me somes tips to make it work?

Comment: Fairly sure the error code means that the xml document contains an invalid character.  Could be a wrong encoding.  Open the file in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `OpenAsync()`? (Further more, doesn't the method named `LoadFromAsync` exist?) 
Please see this Web page: [How to read and write data into XML file In Metro style apps ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/bcb981aa-f2f8-4f73-89db-43439cf03cd2)

By the way, error `0xC00CE508` occurs in many cases, while parsing `XML`. Please check that the contents of the `XML` have no error, by using the `XmlDocument.LoadXml(String)` method.